# Composer warning when trying to get a required private library from toran

Tags: php, composer-php, require, packagist, toran-proxy

When my composer attempts to get a private library from toran, I get this warning:

> Warning from https://toran.dev.lan/repo/packagist: The original
>   providers could not be fetched

Running `composer require app/client:^6.0` gives:

```
user@u:~/Projects/app$ composer require app/client:^6.0
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Warning from https://toran.dev.lan/repo/packagist: The original providers could not be fetched
Warning from https://toran.dev.lan/repo/packagist: The original providers could not be fetched
```

Running `composer require app/client:^6.0 -vvv`
gives:

```
Downloading https://toran.dev.lan/repo/packagist/p/app/accounting-common.json
Warning from https://toran.dev.lan/repo/packagist: The original
providers could not be fetched

Writing /home/user/.composer/cache/repo/https---toran.dev.lan-repo-packagist/provider-app$accounting-common.json into cache

Downloading https://toran.dev.lan/repo/packagist/p/app/php-amqplib-extension.json
Warning from https://toran.dev.lan/repo/packagist: The original providers could not be fetched
Writing /home/user/.composer/cache/repo/https---toran.dev.lan-repo-packagist/provider-app$php-amqplib-extension.json into cache

Downloading https://toran.dev.lan/repo/packagist/p/app/lib-symfony-components.json
Warning from https://toran.dev.lan/repo/packagist: The original providers could not be fetched
Writing /home/user/.composer/cache/repo/https---toran.dev.lan-repo-packagist/provider-app$lib-symfony-components.json into cache

Downloading https://toran.dev.lan/repo/packagist/p/app/lib-dependency-injection.json
Warning from https://toran.dev.lan/repo/packagist: The original providers could not be fetched
Writing /home/user/.composer/cache/repo/https---toran.dev.lan-repo-packagist/provider-app$lib-dependency-injection.json into cache

Downloading https://toran.dev.lan/repo/packagist/p/app/rabbitmq-extension-bundle.json
Warning from https://toran.dev.lan/repo/packagist: The original providers could not be fetched
Writing /home/user/.composer/cache/repo/https---toran.dev.lan-repo-packagist/provider-app$rabbitmq-extension-bundle.json into cache
```

Why am I getting this warning?

Comment: I'm getting this issue as well, and am looking into it. From what I can tell it seems to be related to the public proxies, possibly by having a package that isn't hosted by any of the public proxies.

I'll keep you posted on what I find, and if I find a solution submit an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

It seemed that php version was the problem, the project was at 5.6 and my local php version was 7.0. also I had to launch `composer require` from Project container which uses docker in order to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

This is also a known issue for Composer 1.4+ combined with private packages in Toran. Composer is wrongly fetching the public Toran repository instead of the private one. See this Github issue for more information on the current progress: https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/6383

Currently there is not fix.

Answer (score -1):

I've had this problem as well, and have it no longer.

I had been using Toran to deliver both our private packages AND the public ones (all of which were available through packagist).  By removing the public repository line in our composer.json file everything loaded fine and I didnt get the error any more.

To be clear - we have removed the public repos line AND the {"packagist":"false"} line.